# Validating digital signature using StAX

Tags: java, xml-parsing

How do I validate digital signature on XML using Java StAX API . I already know how to validate using DOM. I have a very big XML file and I need a way to validate the signature using StAX. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

I found this [blog post](https://coheigea.blogspot.ie/2014/03/apache-santuario-xml-security-for-java.html), which points to some code demonstrating a StAX implementation:

> To see how to configure the new inbound StAX-based XML Signature
>   functionality, take a look at the "[verifyUsingStAX](https://github.com/coheigea/testcases/blob/master/apache/santuario/santuario-xml-signature/src/test/java/org/apache/coheigea/santuario/xmlsignature/SignatureUtils.java#L201)" method used by the
>   tests. As with signature creation, it is necessary to create a
>   XMLSecurityProperties Object, and to tell it what "Action" to perform.
>   In addition you must call the following method, unless the complete
>   signing key is contained in the Signature KeyInfo:
>
> - properties.setSignatureVerificationKey(Key) - a key to use to verify
>     the Signature.

https://github.com/coheigea/testcases/blob/master/apache/santuario/santuario-xml-signature/src/test/java/org/apache/coheigea/santuario/xmlsignature/SignatureUtils.java#L201

```
/**
     * Verify the document using the StAX API of Apache Santuario - XML Security for Java.
     */
    public static void verifyUsingStAX(
        InputStream inputStream,
        List<QName> namesToSign,
        X509Certificate cert
    ) throws Exception {
        // Set up the Configuration
        XMLSecurityProperties properties = new XMLSecurityProperties();
        List<XMLSecurityConstants.Action> actions = new ArrayList<XMLSecurityConstants.Action>();
        actions.add(XMLSecurityConstants.SIGNATURE);
        properties.setActions(actions);

        properties.setSignatureVerificationKey(cert.getPublicKey());

        InboundXMLSec inboundXMLSec = XMLSec.getInboundWSSec(properties);

        XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);

        TestSecurityEventListener eventListener = new TestSecurityEventListener();
        XMLStreamReader securityStreamReader = 
            inboundXMLSec.processInMessage(xmlStreamReader, null, eventListener);

        while (securityStreamReader.hasNext()) {
            securityStreamReader.next();
        }
        xmlStreamReader.close();
        inputStream.close();

        // Check that what we were expecting to be signed was actually signed
        List<SignedElementSecurityEvent> signedElementEvents =
            eventListener.getSecurityEvents(SecurityEventConstants.SignedElement);
        Assert.assertNotNull(signedElementEvents);

        for (QName nameToSign : namesToSign) {
            boolean found = false;
            for (SignedElementSecurityEvent signedElement : signedElementEvents) {
                if (signedElement.isSigned()
                    && nameToSign.equals(getSignedQName(signedElement.getElementPath()))) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            Assert.assertTrue(found);
        }

        // Check Signing cert
        X509TokenSecurityEvent tokenEvent =
            (X509TokenSecurityEvent)eventListener.getSecurityEvent(SecurityEventConstants.X509Token);
        Assert.assertNotNull(tokenEvent);

        Assert.assertTrue(tokenEvent.getSecurityToken() instanceof X509SecurityToken);
        X509SecurityToken x509SecurityToken = (X509SecurityToken)tokenEvent.getSecurityToken();
        Assert.assertEquals(x509SecurityToken.getX509Certificates()[0], cert);
    }
```